# Error while sharing the state from mono-repo shell app

Tags: reactjs, monorepo, webpack-module-federation, nx-monorepo

I am trying to share state created with zustand from a mono-repo shell application to an external app outside the mono-repo which is also created using monorepo.

```
type Store = {
  count: number;
  increment: () => void;
};

const sharedStore = create<Store>((set) => ({
  count: 0,
  increment: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count + 1 })),
}));

export default sharedStore;
```

exported from index file like

```
export { default } from './lib/lib-store';
```

when shared normally using

in Recipient:

remotes: [['host', 'http://localhost:4200/remoteEntry.js']],

in host:

exposes: {
'./sharedStore': '../shared/src/lib/lib-store',
},

and then use host/sharedState

this works,
but if I am trying to get this dynamically I m getting below error.
TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
at Function.invokeGetter (:3:28)

to dynamically load I used below code

```
  loadRemoteModule({
      type: 'module',
      remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4200/remoteEntry.js',
      exposedModule: './sharedStore',
    }).then((m) => {
      console.log(`Success:: Loaded external module:`, m);
      onSuccess(m);
    });
```

Module is loaded.

tsconfig in both projects has

```
"alwaysStrict": false,
```

What could be the reason?